# Acquire a lock on a file

Tags: java

I want to acqeuire a lock on a file when threo read gets started on a specific  file ,so that no other application can read the file which has been already locked and want to release the lock file when thread terminates.

Comment: "No other application" ... do you really want OS-level mandatory locking? At least in the Unix world, it's pretty inconvenient and very rare. *Advisory locking* is much more common and reliable, but it does require all processes to cooperate. Not sure about Windows. What platform? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

You can acquire a [FileLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html) via a [FileChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html). To obtain a FileChannel:

> In this release a file channel can be obtained from an existing [FileInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#getChannel--), [FileOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#getChannel--), or [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#getChannel--) object by invoking that object's getChannel method, which returns a file channel that is connected to the same underlying file.

However, Java doesn't have control over what type of file locking the OS offers and therefore the recommendation of the API is to use the lock as if it were an advisory file lock.

> Whether or not a lock actually prevents another program from accessing the content of the locked region is system-dependent and therefore unspecified. The native file-locking facilities of some systems are merely advisory, meaning that programs must cooperatively observe a known locking protocol in order to guarantee data integrity. On other systems native file locks are mandatory, meaning that if one program locks a region of a file then other programs are actually prevented from accessing that region in a way that would violate the lock. On yet other systems, whether native file locks are advisory or mandatory is configurable on a per-file basis. To ensure consistent and correct behavior across platforms, it is strongly recommended that the locks provided by this API be used as if they were advisory locks.

Answer (score 0):

Once you read and keep a stream to a file, OS will lock other processes from accessing that file except reading it.

In Windows, I know some applications allow you to search for the process locking a file and kill it as well. **[Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/)** is my favorite one.