# File-based equivalent of java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock?

Tags: java, java-6, file-locking

I am looking for a file-based lock with API similar to `java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock` (e.g. `ReentrantLock`). I would really like to have `tryLock()` as well as its time-bound little sister, without the need to create and manipulate files, clean up after myself and spend time perfecting the concurrent implementation (what is hard and easy to get wrong).

Is it available in core Java 6 or some popular and widely used (and tested) libraries?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315553/acquire-a-lock-on-a-file

Comment: I know how to lock a file. I'm looking for a complete higher-level implementation that nicely wraps all the concurrency and file manipulation behind a clean API.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is hard to lock files. I used [FileChannel.lock()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#lock%28%29) or tryLock()

Comment: I share this opinion, that's why I'm asking for an existing implementation that does it for me.

Comment: Check [FileChannelPool](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/wicket/releases/wicket-1.5-RC5.1/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/pageStore/FileChannelPool.java)